# Failed to execute

Tags: java, maven

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project gameoflife-core: Compilation failure
>   [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are
>   running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

I have already Java installed on my machine, but still facing the issue.

Im working on EC2.

Comment: Please provide more information of what you are trying to do.

Comment: im trying build maven project on ec2 rhel. i already have java installed on my machine, but during compile i getting the error

Comment: what is the command that you ran that produced this error? how did you install java? Please update your question with this information. The more information you provide, the more likely you are receiving an answer to it...

Comment: command i ran is mvn compile....installed java by " wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u141-b15/336fa29ff2bb4ef291e347e091f7f4a7/jdk-8u141-linux-x64.rpm
"

Comment: `wget` does only download the JDK, it doesn't install it. Maybe maven cannot find the JDK since it is not installed?

Comment: i got it resolved by this. http://openjdk.java.net/install/

Answer (score -1):

Do you have java development kit (JDK) installed (Not java) ? if not then  Maybe you have to download it
[Here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comment: Do i need to set path in /etc/envi.  please guide

Comment: i have only terminal access, how do i download jdk?

Comment: when im trying to dowload jdk, some text/html file is getting dowloaded